# Scroll bars dissapear when I use DoCmd.Maximize On Open Event - Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm using DoCmd.Maximize On the Open event of a "split-form", so that it the form fills the screen when opened.

Unfortunately, this seems to remove the scroll bars for the form, which I have set in the form's properties. There is a requirement for the scrolls as info does extend beyond the screens real estate. 
Cant seem to find a solution anywhere to this problem, is there an alternative to maximising the form to fill the screen?

Any help greatley appreciated

Cheers

Noel

Comment: I do not have this problem. Which scroll bars do you expect to see, horizontal or vertical? Which controls are missing?

Comment: Hi Remou, perhaps I should have been clearer, I'm having difficulty with a split form that isn't showing the horizontal scroll bar (Scroll bars are set to 'both') that is required. I have a feeling I must be missing something obvious here but I cant for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll bars do not appear when the form is large enough to display all its contents.  (The screen area for the scroll bars is still reserved, however, which you can see if you play with the colors.)

Comment: Hi Phoog, yeah i appreciate that the scroll bars need to be invoked so to speak. As I said above to Remou, the problem I have is with a split form that needs a horizontal scroll bar to see all the data in the datasheet but its not displaying for some reason. Any ideas?! I'm baffled!